# Why does my keypad fails abruptly?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, keyboard

I use samsung galaxy y duos.And my samsung keypad fails abruptly at times.When I tap in the places where I need to give in the words,keypad appears but when I type in, the keypad works nice but there aren't any word in the input box.It happens in all kind of application and messaging.What should I do prevent this happen ever again.Somebody please edit this question with good english.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with my  new Samsung Galaxy Tab 3. When I wanted to write a post 
for a forum I got the writing window and the keyboard but when I typed three letters 
the keyboard vanished and this problem continued.
Later I discovered how to really shut down the tablet by pressing the switch-off a bit longer.
Then I got a message: Switch off the tablet? I clicked okay. When I turned on 
my tablet again after some time the trouble with writing was gone.

Comment: Problem persists even after doing.Will this be an activity by a virus?